# Only outputs first user in database not user that logged in

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.android

When a user logs in, no matter which login it is, the user data given is always the first user that entered the database.

I cleared the database and tested it again and the results were the same, the first user in the database information shows up for any user login.

I think the problem might be the call on the logged in page `FirstOrDefault` or maybe SharedPreference as I'm not 100% of either of these commands.

[DBHelper class](https://pastebin.com/YngmDRbn) which is used in the below code.

Edit 1: Tested the username passed through sharedpreferences with toast, and it did not output so maybe the sharedpreferences isn't passing the data so it only displays the first entry in the database?

Edit 2: Code for DBHelper GetUser

```
    public static async Task<users> GetUser(string userName)
    {
        CurrentPlatform.Init();
        List<users> ls = await MobileService.GetTable<users>().ToListAsync();
        users u = ls.FirstOrDefault(x => x.username == userName);
        return u;
    }
```

Edit 3: Tested to see if **Username** contained the right value with a toast on the login page, which it does but looks as if the value doesn't pass on to the page it logins too. Am i passing the sharedpreference value wrong?

Here is my login code:

```
public class Dialog_SignIn : Activity
{

    public static MobileServiceClient Client =
    new MobileServiceClient("https://app.azurewebsites.net");

    //static ISharedPreferences pref = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("UserInfo", FileCreationMode.Private);
    //ISharedPreferencesEditor edit = pref.Edit();

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Set our view from the "sign in" layout resource
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Dialog_Sign_In);

        //ISharedPreferences pref = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("UserInfo", FileCreationMode.Private);
        //ISharedPreferencesEditor edit = pref.Edit();

        EditText username = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtUsername);
        EditText password = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtPassword);
        //username.Text = pref.GetString("UserName", "");
        //password.Text = pref.GetString("Password", "");
        var login = FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnDialogSignin);
        login.Click += TryLoginAsync;
    }

    private async void TryLoginAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EditText txtUsername = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtUsername);
        EditText txtPassword = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.txtPassword);
        string user = txtUsername.Text.Trim();
        string zPassword = txtPassword.Text;

        if (!await DBHelper.DoesUserExist(user))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Invalid Login", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            users u = await DBHelper.GetUser(user);
            if (PasswordStorage.VerifyPassword(zPassword, u.password))
            {
                ISharedPreferences pref = GetSharedPreferences("UserInfo", FileCreationMode.Private);
                ISharedPreferencesEditor edit = pref.Edit();
                //edit.PutString("Username", u.username);
                //edit.PutString("Password", u.password);
                edit.PutString("UserID", u.ID);
                edit.PutString("UserName", u.username);
                edit.PutString("LoggedIn", "true");
                edit.PutString("Password", u.password);
                edit.Apply();
                Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, "Success", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                if (await DBHelper.IsUserProfileCreated(u.ID))
                {
                    //go to main menu
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Profile", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    StartActivity(typeof(MainProfile));
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Logged In and user made", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    StartActivity(typeof(SetUpProfile));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Invalid Login", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void GoToMain(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
    }
}
```

And heres the page it displays if username and password match:

```
public class MainProfile : Activity
{
    public static MobileServiceClient Client =
    new MobileServiceClient("https://app.azurewebsites.net");

    protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main_Profile);
        ISharedPreferences pref = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("UserInfo", FileCreationMode.Private);
        ISharedPreferencesEditor edit = pref.Edit();
        String userID = pref.GetString("UserID", null);
        String username = pref.GetString("Username", null);
        String loggedIn = pref. GetString("LoggedIn", null);
        String password = pref.GetString("Password", null);
        var homeBTN = FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnHome);
        var eventsBTN = FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnEvents);
        var connectionsBTN = FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnConnections);
        var logout = FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnLogout);

        CurrentPlatform.Init();
        List<UserProf> ls = await Client.GetTable<UserProf>().ToListAsync();
        UserProf prof = ls.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == username);
        TextView textName = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.textName);
        textName.Text = prof.Firstname;
        TextView textCounty = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.textCounty);
        textCounty.Text = prof.County;
        TextView textProfession = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.textProfession);
        textProfession.Text = prof.Profession;
        TextView textDescription = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.textDescription);
        textDescription.Text = prof.Description;

        homeBTN.Click += HomeProcess;
        eventsBTN.Click += EventProcess;
        connectionsBTN.Click += ConnectionsProcess;
        logout.Click += LogoutProcess;

        Toast.MakeText(this, "Hello " + prof.Firstname + " " + prof.Lastname, ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
    private void HomeProcess(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ISharedPreferences prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("UserInfo", FileCreationMode.Private);
        ISharedPreferencesEditor edit = prefs.Edit();
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Home Page", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        StartActivity(typeof(MainProfile));
    }
    private void EventProcess(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ISharedPreferences prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("UserInfo", FileCreationMode.Private);
        ISharedPreferencesEditor edit = prefs.Edit();
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Events(soon)", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        StartActivity(typeof(Events));
    }
    private void ConnectionsProcess(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ISharedPreferences prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("UserInfo", FileCreationMode.Private);
        ISharedPreferencesEditor edit = prefs.Edit();
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Your Connections", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        //StartActivity(typeof(Connections));
    }
    private void LogoutProcess(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ISharedPreferences prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("UserInfo", FileCreationMode.Private);
        ISharedPreferencesEditor edit = prefs.Edit();
        edit.Remove("UserID");
        edit.Remove("UserName");
        edit.Remove("LoggedIn");
        edit.Remove("Password");
        edit.Apply();
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Logged Out", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you should post is the one for `DBHelper.GetUser(user)`.

Comment: @dcg updated it with GetUser Code, I did a toast notification to test 'username' when logged in that passed through sharedpreferences and nothing outputted